# ClickOnce Application Deployment target application change

Tags: clickonce

I deployed a ClickOnce application last year and have been developing the next version. Let's say the first application was called app2010 and the new one is app2011. Is there a way to set app2010 to download app2011 when it updates and to uninstall app2010 so that when the user runs the application they get app2011?

Thanks

Vic

Edit: app2010 updates using the a call to the ClickOnce deployment.AsyncUpdate() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, it turns out that all you need is to persist the assembly and certificate values and the old app will update without a problem to the new one.

Comment: Hi Varak, what values are you referring to, the Assembly full name?